# Es posible enviar credenciales como tokens desde angular de forma segura?

Tags: angular, api, tokens, peticiones

Tengo una duda que quisiera que me puediera aclarar alguien con experiencia en Angular. Ante todo se que es un framework de frontend y se supone que toda la seguridad se debe dejar a cargo del backend, pero ando buscando opciones antes de sumergirme a hacer algo en el backend, ya que por los momentos solo se algo de frontend. Es posible enviar credenciales de acceso a una API desde Angular de forma segura sin que alguien pueda interceptarlos? estoy tratando de conectarme a una API de un Software CRM y en primera instancia no pude por que me bloquean la peticion a traves de CORS, me comnunique con ellos y me dijeron que las peticiones debian hacerse desde mi backend y sobre todo lo dicen es por la seguridad, entonces esta es mi gran pregunta, estuve buscando y no encontre algo que me permita en angular enviar credenciales de forma segura y por esa razon recurro a este medio para confirmar. Estaria agradecido con sus opiniones y sugerencias. gracias de antemano!

Comment: desde tu front end puedes enviar tu peticion de login tu conexion la realizas mediante https, esa comunicacion es una comunicacion segura desde el cliente hasta el servidor, si el login esta bien se devuelve un token de conexion para las subsecuentes peticiones.

Comment: el API a la que me estoy conectando ya me dio un id y token, lo unico que debo hacer es hacer la peticiones con ese id y ese token para obtener los datos.

Comment: Mi duda se presenta al enviar ese token al api, eso lo debería hacer desde angular o deberia hacer un servicio (backend) para enviar ese token? la duda surgió por que los dueños del api a la que me estoy conectando me dijeron que si lo hacia a traves de Angular por seguridad no era recomendado, y que deberia hacer una aplicacion backend que sirva como de intermediario entre mi front y el API. soy nuevo en Angular y tal vez por eso estoy perdido.

Comment: el token de tu api es solo para uso desde tu servidor no la puedes compartir con tus usuarios,  para el front end si consideras necesario puedes establecer un login y el token de sesion para cada usuario, es decir es independiente tu token de usuario con los servicios que tu consumes

Comment: Tengo entendido que el token que ellos me dieron lo necesito enviar en cada peticion para poder obtener los datos. simplemente pensaba hacer una pagina web en Angular y con sumir esa API desde esa pagina, sin hacer un codigo de backend. no se si estoy confundido o que, pero yo solo se un poco de angular y nada de backend y este es un problema que me asignaron.

Comment: Para este caso debes implementar un microservicio - tu backend - tu sitio en angular consume tu microservicio y tu microservicio se conecta usando el token si tu cambias de proveedor de datos simplemente haces el cambio en tu backend sin afectar a tu sitio de angular.

Comment: Ok, y eso no seria ilogico en cierto aspecto ? es decir, para que crear un servicio y su api ya tiene todo para obtener los datos a traves de cada ruta del API ?